# I delete duplicate packages but Canonical keeps reinstalling them, Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: apt, updates, package-management

files at /var/lib/apt/lists

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
W: Duplicate ...
...
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

But, of course, running `apt-get update` only reinstalls them! How can I fix this?

Comment: Run `sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list`, and look for the duplicate entries listed in the message and remove one of the two lines.